# Closing Handles/Stored Handles

Tags: c++, windows, handle

I have some event handles and I add them to a list. I want to know if I can store these handles, close the local ones and still use the stored ones later.

Example:

```
std::map<std::string, HANDLE> Events;

DWORD OpenSingleEvent(std::string EventName, bool InheritHandle, DWORD dwDesiredAccess, DWORD dwMilliseconds)
{
    Handle hEvent = OpenEvent(dwDesiredAccess, InheritHandle, EventName.c_str()); //Local Handle.
    if (hEvent)
    {
        DeleteSingleEvent(EventName); //Delete the correct/old handle in the map.
        Events.insert(EventName, hEvent);  //Add this new handle to the map.
        DWORD Result = WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, dwMilliseconds);
        CloseHandle(hEvent);  //Close THIS handle. Not the one in my Map.
        return Result;
    }
    CloseHandle(hEvent);  //Close this handle.
    return WAIT_FAILED;
}
```

Will the above work? If not, is there another way to do this? It's for shared memory communication so I cannot duplicate handles since I only have the client PID not the Server's.

Also can someone explain what InheritHandle does? The function I use is OpenEvent and it has that parameter but I'm not sure what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `HANDLE` is simply a `void *`, it's a token which actually represents an object in kernel space.  Calling `CloseHandle` actually deallocates the kernel object so the short answer to your question is no, you can't keep a list of them and then close all the local ones.  All you'll have is a list of `void*` which don't represent anything.

What you can do is use `DuplicateHandle` which actually creates another kernel object on your behalf.  However... why not just close the handles when you've finished with the entry in the list?

Comment: I should also point out, in your question you're calling `CloseHandle` even if the event is `NULL`.  This won't do any harm but it's pointless.

Comment: The list of Handles represent the list of event and I was thinking I can close the local one and then use ResetEvent with the one in the list, etc..

It's kind of useless to close it there I guess. I just didn't like the idea of keeping the handle open is all. Also what does inherit handle do?

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames once you've called `CloseHandle`, there is no event any more to call `ResetEvent` on.  The object has gone.  You can store as many copies of the `HANDLE` as you like but you've really only got one object in the kernel.